# Как экранировать спецсимволы в строке функцией на Golang

Tags: mysql, golang

Есть ли на Go функция экранирования спецсимволов. Можно и самому написать, но интересно есть ли готовая.

Нужно выполнить Mysql запрос по строке содержащей спецсимволы чтобы они учитывались.
Возможно есть на Sql что-то похожее?

Comment: А оборачивание текста в тройное ` не то что нужно?

Answer (score 0):

https://pkg.go.dev/strconv#Quote

```
func main() {
s := strconv.Quote(`"Fran & Freddie's Diner ☺"`)
fmt.Println(s)
}
```

Будет выведено ""Fran & Freddie's Diner\t☺""